# Determining labels for timeseries

Tags: dl4j

I have `csv` data from various weather sensors like [real data is far more complex from many sensors]:

```
TimePeriod    Temp      Pressure      WindSpeed
1,            16,        100,          57
2,            18,        96,           71
```

There is also the "result": Snow, Rain, Sunny, Wind Shear, etc for each time period.

I want to train a Neural Network to learn from the data to predict the "result". I have sufficient data to create both training and test datasets.

I am stuck at "go" on the Vectorization!  I think I simply have one large CSV file for a period of several months as training data.

Would that limit me to a single Label?

For time-series predictions such as this, I haven't been able to find a good example about setting up such training data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't the Iris dataset somewhat similar to what you have?

https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples/blob/7b4d76c9ff8de7697a1ff97ee917a10f5f3873e3/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/examples/dataexamples/CSVExample.java

Comment: Yes!  While I may feel dumb, I am so flipping happy to have this straight in my head now!  Hopefully obviously, I had not seen that example!

Comment: it's easy to overlook stuff in the net-data-jungle ;)